# How should I implement OOP patterns to interactive web applications (with the aide of jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, web-applications, interactive

Sometimes, using jQuery induces you to abuse its power (at least for me because of its selector matching capability). Event handlers here and there. Utility functions here and everywhere. Code coherence can almost seem nonexistent. I want to alleviate that problem by implementing OOP patterns, but since I have C++ and python background, implementing it in javascript is weirding me out a little bit.

The code below uses OOP patterns, but I'm not entirely sure if my implementations are good practices. The reason I'm doubting my implementations is because of the 3rd comment in [my last stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905201/how-to-access-instance-property-in-an-instance-method-when-the-method-is-being-p). I know it's only one certain detail in my code he commented on, but it also makes me wonder about the other patterns I'm implementing in my code.

I would really appreciate if you could point out the flaws and pitfalls in my patterns and/or if you have any suggestions. Many thanks in advance.

(this code is an simplification of something I'm developing, but the idea is similar)

[Live Example](http://initfortheladies.com/tri-upload/oop-technique.html)

```
$(function(){
    var stream = new Stream();
});


/*          Stream Class
------------------------------------------*/
function Stream(){

    // Disables multiple Stream objects
    if (this.singleton)
        return
    else
        this.__proto__.singleton = true;


    this.elements = jQueryMapping(this.selectors) // Converts a map of selectors to a map of jQuery objects
    this.initEvents();
}

Stream.prototype.singleton = false;

Stream.prototype.selectors = {
    stream : '#stream',
    post_content : '#post-content',
    add_post: '#add-post',
    // ... more action selectors
}

Stream.prototype.initEvents = function(){
    this.elements.add_post.click(this, this.addPost);
    // ... more action event-listeners
}

Stream.prototype.addPost = function(e){
    var self = e.data;
    var post_content = self.elements.post_content.val();

    if (post_content)
        self.elements.stream.append(new Post(post_content));
}


/*          Post Class
------------------------------------------*/
function Post(post_content){
    this.$element = $('<li>')
                        .text(post_content)
                        .append('<button class="delete-post">Delete</button>');

    this.elements = jQueryMapping(this.selectors, this.$element);
    this.initEvents();

    return this.$element;
}

Post.prototype.selectors = {
    delete_post: 'button.delete-post',
    // ... more action selectors
}

Post.prototype.initEvents = function(){
    this.elements.delete_post.click(this.deletePost);
    // ... more action event-listeners
}

Post.prototype.deletePost = function(){
    $(this).parent().slideUp();
}


/*          Utils
------------------------------------------*/
function jQueryMapping(map, context){
    // Converts a map of selectors to a map of jQuery objects

    var $map = {};
    $.each(map, function(key, value){ 
            $map[key] = (context) ? $(value, context) : $(value);
    });

    return $map;
}
```

Comment: Off topic, but you loose most of what makes oop great when you don't have compile time enforcment...

Comment: Do not use `__proto__`, it's non-standard and unsupported by some browsers.

Comment: @ByronWhitlock Preference of Strict typing vs loose typing is a complete tangent to OOP.

Comment: This sort of question is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @matt, cool, I didn't know that site existed. Thanks. This question somewhat overlapped though, because I was asking OOP patterns and I was just using that code for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your code is over engineered. I've re factored and it simplified it as can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/avVGT/5/). If you really want a heavy OOP setup I recommend you use a clientside MVC (Backbone, knockout, etc) construct to do it properly or keep it light instead.

I'll proceed with general feedback on your code.

```
/*          Stream Class
------------------------------------------*/
function Stream(){

    // Disables multiple Stream objects
    if (this.singleton)
        return
    else
        this.__proto__.singleton = true;


    this.elements = jQueryMapping(this.selectors) // Converts a map of selectors to a map of jQuery objects
    this.initEvents();
}
```

There is no reason to use a singleton like this. It's also *very* bad to use `.__proto__`

I would recommend pattern like this instead.

```
var Stream = (function() {
    var Stream = function() { ... };

    // prototype stuff

    var stream = new Stream();

    return function() {
         return stream;
    };
})());
```

Storing a hash of data like that on the prototype is unneccesary.

```
Stream.prototype.selectors = {
    stream : '#stream',
    post_content : '#post-content',
    add_post: '#add-post',
    // ... more action selectors
}
```

You can include this as a defaults hash instead.

```
(function() {
    var defaults = {
        stream : '#stream',
        post_content : '#post-content',
        add_post: '#add-post',
        // ... more action selectors
    }

    function Stream() {
         ...

         this.elements = jQueryMapping(defaults);
    }

}());
```

Your utility function could be optimised slightly.

```
$map[key] = (context) ? $(value, context) : $(value);
```

This could be rewritten as

```
$map[key] = $(value, context)
```

Since if `context` is undefined you just pass in an undefined paramater which is the same as passing in no parameter.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize javascript MVC frameworks exists. I'll for sure look into that. Thanks.

On the other hand, thanks for the great code tips.

Comment: I'd recommend backbone/spine or knockout instead because jsmvc brings a lot of bloat for something lightweight. Although it's great if your doing the entire website with it in mind

Answer (score 1):

The title of this reads "for beginners", but I've found [this section](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#designpatternsjavascript) on design patterns, and [this section](http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#designpatternsjquery) on design patterns using jQuery useful.

Comment: I'm not sure that the 2nd section you linked is all that relevant to the OP. It's more design patterns that have been applied in jQuery, and less how to apply design patterns to your own code.